Does there always exist a bijection between $A$ and $A \times A$ (A is an uncountably infinite set)?
If $A$ is any infinite set, does there always exist a bijection between $A$ and $A ^n$?
I know that this is true for countable $A$ and for $\mathbb{R}$. It should also be sufficient to show this for $n=2$ in order to prove it for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Original question:
Let $A$ be any infinite set (you should not assume that $A$ is countable; it can be
the set of real numbers). Let $B$ be some finite set and let $P$ = {$f$ ∶ $B$ → $A$}. Is there a bijection between
$A$ and $P$?
Here, if $|B|=n$, I believe it is sufficient to show bijection between $A$ and $A^n$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice

@Lucenaposition The refusal to publish Tarski's theorem because "Fréchet wrote that an implication between two well known propositions is not a new result. Lebesgue wrote that an implication between two false propositions is of no interest." seems wild to me, seen with modern eyes.

Assuming choice, $A\cong A\times A$ for any infinite set $A$ - as a theorem of ZFC. Without choice, I believe I am right in saying this is true so long as $A$ is well-ordered (or well-orderable).
Here is one proof.

Sorry, my comment was wrong. I have deleted it.
